# Clang-Format incorrectly adds a space between a shift operators >> in a for loop

Tags: c++, clang-format

The code snippets:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; ++i, k = k >> 1) {
printf();
}
```

will be turned into

```
for (i = 0; i<j; ++i, k = k > > 1) {
printf();
}
```

By my experiments,
`(i<j;k=k>>1);`
will be turned into
`(i<j; k = k> > 1);`

which is incorrect, the shift operator should not be separated.

Is this a known issue? I am using clang-format-10.

Comment: I could not reproduce on : https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/ with clang-format-10 and default settings

Comment: I could not reproduce.  What command line and style configuration are you using for clang-format?

Comment: That's strange!
$ clang-format-10 --version
clang-format version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
$ clang-format-10 --style=google test.cpp and I get 
for (i = 0; i<j; ++i, k = k> > 1) {
  printf();
}

Comment: Test on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: I found that a newer version, say clang-format 14.0.6 (downloaded from https://pypi.org/project/clang-format/#files), does not have this issue.